# AutoHotkey - paste the expanded text instead of "typing" it

Tags: autohotkey

In AutoHotkey, I have the following script:

```
:o:divc::<div align="center"></div>
```

When I use it in my IDE, the IDE will auto-close the `div` while it's being written by AutoHotkey, resulting in something like this:

```
<div align="center"></div></div>
```

The result is an extra `div` which I don't need. Is there a way to modify the AutoHotkey script so that it just pastes the expanded text without "typing" it on screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
Clipboard = <div align="center"></div>
Send ^v
```

Comment: If you want the clipboard contents to persist, you can bracket this with `ClipSaved := ClipboardAll` ... (do stuff) ... `Clipboard := ClipSaved`. See [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm).